# Blueimp jQuery file upload rails: BMP image preview issue

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, bmp, blueimp

I can upload BMP image files in my rails application using Blueimp jQuery file upload rails. But I could not preview BMP file only. How to fix this issue?

[Blueimp - Sebastian explained this is an browser issue](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/1549964-client-side-preview-does-not-work-for-bmp-files-on-android-native-and-chrome-browsers-both) but in dropzone.js they are displaying the image in using canvas data.

I want to preview bmp image before upload. Even I found the way to convert BMP file in 2 methods,

1. [external method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877876/bmp-decoding-in-javascript-and-drawing-to-explorer-canvas?rq=1)
2. var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL()

Now the problem is that, I could not find the respective callback method in bluimp. I am using jquery-fileupload-rails gem.

Anybody resolved this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BMP file could not be previewed using blueimp jquery file upload rails.

Answer (score 1):

the current version that I use does allow BMP preview, just pass in the following option:

```js
loadImageFileTypes: /^image\/(bmp|gif|jpeg|png)$/,
```